How to switch back from uniform to fine-grained access permissions?
I switched my bucket from fine-grained access permissions to uniform, to try out managed folders. The UI assured me that I have 90 days to change back to fine-grained:

All object access is controlled by bucket permissions and objects cannot have their own access control lists (ACLs). To allow per-object access, you can switch to fine-grained access within 90 days.

But when I do, using the button under the text, I get an error:

Unable to update access control. Invalid request for a uniform bucket-level access resource

What can I do?
--- edit ---
Running this command gave me a hint:
gsutil uniformbucketlevelaccess set off gs://mybucket


Disabling Uniform bucket-level access for gs://mybucket...
BadRequestException: 400 Uniform bucket-level access is required to be enabled on the bucket when there are managed folders in the bucket. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access

Apparently I have a managed folder but I forgot which one and I can't find it in the UI.



So yes indeed, the solution was to remove all managed folders first before switching back to fine-grained.
You can list the managed folders using:
gcloud storage managed-folders list gs://mybucket

If Google is listening, it would be great if you could extend the gcloud console error message to make it more informative.
